# How to start mongo docker image with db user and password

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, docker

i am trying to docker-ize my nodejs/mongodb/mongoose app.
In my app.js i have the call to the local db:

```js
mongoose.connect('mongodb://'mydbuser":"+mydbpassword"@"localhost"/"+nodekb,{ useMongoClient: true });
```

My service part within th docker-compose.yml is looking like that:

```js
  mongo:
    image: "mongo"
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
```

I am using the default docker mongo image.
My local mongo is using the mongo config file "mongod.cfg":

```js
systemLog:
    destination: file
    path: "C:\\data\\log\\mongod.log"
storage:
    dbPath: "C:\\data"
net:
    port: 27017
security:
    authorization: enabled
setParameter:
    enableLocalhostAuthBypass: false
```

How can i inject the dbadmin, dbpw and the mongo config file so that it is used from the docker mongo image, wenn i do docker-compose up ?
I guess with the COPY command it is easy to inject the mongo config, but how can i tell the image to use it ?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: There are configuration examples with environment variables on the docker image page: https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo/

Comment: You can pass environment variables for the username and password and dbname, and you can use a volume to set the config

Comment: Say Docker wasn't involved, but the MongoDB installation was too big to fit on your development system and you had to run it somewhere else.  How would you configure that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Halil's answer is correct when you want to connect to DB "root".

But if you want to connect to DB "nodekb" rather than "root", you should first run "db.createUser()" command(https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.createUser/index.html) on DB "nodekb". Unfortunately, there is no way to setup this in "docker-compose.yml".

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the related information under environment. It is clear on the docs.

Basic setup would be like below.

```js
mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    environment: 
       MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
       MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
```

Comment: Hi Halil,
thanks for the snippet, but yes i was aware of this snippet within the doc.
But i am still getting Authentication failed error.
So what i did was: i ve put the lines into my docker-compose.yml and did docker-compose build and docker-compose up, i also used 3T to access mongodb by UI and i have created a user  ... did the memtioned steps again, same issue

Comment: I guess it has something to do with this: "Do note that none of the variables below will have any effect if you start the container with a data directory that already contains a database: any pre-existing database will always be left untouched on container startup."

Comment: Hi there,  i checked the snippet i shared, i have found out that i have shared for mongo-express lib. I have corrected it, could you please try like the updated one ? I have tried on my local environment a moment ago and authentication working as expected. Could you please try and inform ?

Comment: Don't forget to `docker-compose build && docker-compose up` after add the environment variables to docker-compose.yml